# Cauchy–Schwarz inequality for complex-valued functions

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{C}$. I wonder if the following inequality, with no absolute value, is true:
$$\left(\int_0^1 f(x) \overline{g(x)}\ dx\right)^2\leq \int_0^1 f(x)^2\ dx\int_0^1 g(x)^2\ dx$$

Comment: Wouldn't the right-hand side be a complex number, then?

Comment: Even the left hand side would be complex

Comment: What is your definition of $\le$ for complex numbers?

Comment: Indeed! Somehow I didn't notice the glaring lack of absolute value on the left...

Comment: checkout, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.06031.pdf but the definition of inner product is little complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true.

Consider $f(x)=g(x)=\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Observe that

$$ \int_{0}^{1} f(x)\overline{g(x)}dx = \int_{0}^{1} 1 dx =1$$

And note that

$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x)^2dx=i =\int_{0}^{1}g(x)^2 dx $$

Thus, if the inequality is true,

$$(1)^2\leq (i)(i)=-1  $$

And it is a contradiction.

Thus, the given f(x) and g(x) make a counter example of your inequality.